# Matlab: duplicate blocks of elements in a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, duplicates, repeat

I want to repeat the elements of a vector, but considering blocks of elements (without using any loops).

For example, considering a block of size 2, I have a vector like this `a = [1:6]` and I want the output to look like this `out = [1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 5 6 5 6]`.

Comment: For a block of a size 3 what is the expected output?

Comment: `out = [1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6]`.

Comment: And for a block of size 5?

Comment: I only consider cases where block size is a divider of the number of elements in a (`mod(length (a), block_size) == 0`)

Comment: `out = reshape(repmat(reshape(a,blocksize,[]),2,1),1,[])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reshape` your input and then repeat it as needed using `repmat`

```
blksize = 2;

tmp = repmat(reshape(a, blksize, 1, []), 1, blksize, 1);

output = tmp(:).';
```

**Explanation**

First we want to reshape your matrix into an `blksize x 1 x (numel(a)/blksize)` matrix.

```
A = reshape(a, blksize, 1, []);
```

Then we want to repeat `A` `blksize` times along the second dimension to create the necessary number of repeats.

```
B = repmat(A, 1, blksize, 1);
```

We then flatten the entire thing into an array and thanks to the column-major ordering we get the desired output

```
output = B(:).'
```

**Optional One-Liner**

If you really want one line you can use `reshape` again rather than `(:).'`

```
output = reshape(repmat(reshape(a, blksize, 1, []), 1, blksize, 1), 1, []);
```

**Alternative**

You could also use MATLAB's `repelem` to accomplish the repeating

```
result = reshape(repelem(reshape(a, blksize, 1, []), 1, blksize, 1), 1, [])
```